# How to Templatize Repeated tasks in python want to templatize KubernetesPodOperator( .... ) and just Call Runtime variable

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, directed-acyclic-graphs

## Need to templatize kubernets pod operator

```
document       = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace=namespace,image=image,cmds=["/bin/bash","-c", spark_template.render(report_name="document")],image_pull_policy='IfNotPresent',volume_mounts=[volume_mount],volumes=[volume],name="table-loader_document",task_id="document",get_logs=True,dag=dag,on_failure_callback=sns_notify_fail,trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,is_delete_operator_pod=False,config_file=kube_config_path,in_cluster=False,cluster_context='aws')
        dnf            = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace=namespace,image=image,cmds=["/bin/bash","-c", spark_template.render(report_name="dnf")],image_pull_policy='IfNotPresent',volume_mounts=[volume_mount],volumes=[volume],name="table-loader_dnf",task_id="dnf",get_logs=True,dag=dag,on_failure_callback=sns_notify_fail,trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,is_delete_operator_pod=False,config_file=kube_config_path,in_cluster=False,cluster_context='aws')
          comments       = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace=namespace,image=image,cmds=["/bin/bash","-c", spark_template.render(report_name="comments")],image_pull_policy='IfNotPresent',volume_mounts=[volume_mount],volumes=[volume],name="table-loader_comments",task_id="comments",get_logs=True,dag=dag,on_failure_callback=sns_notify_fail,trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,is_delete_operator_pod=False,config_file=kube_config_path,in_cluster=False,cluster_context='aws')
          cc             = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace=namespace,image=image,cmds=["/bin/bash","-c", spark_template.render(report_name="cc")],image_pull_policy='IfNotPresent',volume_mounts=[volume_mount],volumes=[volume],name="table-loader_cc",task_id="cc",get_logs=True,dag=dag,on_failure_callback=sns_notify_fail,trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,is_delete_operator_pod=False,config_file=kube_config_path,in_cluster=False,cluster_context='aws')
          capf           = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace=namespace,image=image,cmds=["/bin/bash","-c", spark_template.render(report_name="capf")],image_pull_policy='IfNotPresent',volume_mounts=[volume_mount],volumes=[volume],name="table-loader_capf",task_id="capf",get_logs=True,dag=dag,on_failure_callback=sns_notify_fail,trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,is_delete_operator_pod=False,config_file=kube_config_path,in_cluster=False,cluster_context='aws')
          capa           = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace=namespace,image=image,cmds=["/bin/bash","-c", spark_template.render(report_name="capa")],image_pull_policy='IfNotPresent',volume_mounts=[volume_mount],volumes=[volume],name="table-loader_capa",task_id="capa",get_logs=True,dag=dag,on_failure_callback=sns_notify_fail,trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,is_delete_operator_pod=False,config_file=kube_config_path,in_cluster=False,cluster_context='aws')
          actions        = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace=namespace,image=image,cmds=["/bin/bash","-c", spark_template.render(report_name="actions")],image_pull_policy='IfNotPresent',volume_mounts=[volume_mount],volumes=[volume],name="table-loader_actions",task_id="actions",get_logs=True,dag=dag,on_failure_callback=sns_notify_fail,on_success_callback=sns_notify_success,trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,is_delete_operator_pod=False,config_file=kube_config_path,in_cluster=False,cluster_context='aws')
          
         document   >> dnf        >> comments   >> cc         >> capf       >> capa       >> actions
```

Comment: you are probably the only one who understands the question. What do you want to do?

Comment: @rioV8 Thanks for update . In Above Variables only Kuberbernets operator is is every time repeating i want to variableize in one set and call all runtime values in it like report name, name,task_idi want to use repetitive taks in for loop

Answer (score 0):

Write the following snippet for the languageID of the file

```
"KubernetesPodOperator": {
  "prefix": "kpo",
  "body": [
    "$1 = KubernetesPodOperator(namespace=namespace,image=image,cmds=[\"/bin/bash\",\"-c\", spark_template.render(report_name=\"$1\")],image_pull_policy='IfNotPresent',volume_mounts=[volume_mount],volumes=[volume],name=\"table-loader_$1\",task_id=\"$1\",get_logs=True,dag=dag,on_failure_callback=sns_notify_fail,trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_DONE,is_delete_operator_pod=False,config_file=kube_config_path,in_cluster=False,cluster_context='aws')\n$0"
  ],
  "description": "variable = KubernetesPodOperator(...)"
}
```

Comment: rioV8  Thanks for Code Snippet ,  Is it python code  what i need to add in variable = KubernetesPodOperator(...)

Comment: @jayesh_mahajan Read the snippets doc of VSC on how to use and where to define them

Comment: we need above to run  solution in taks of airflow  dag i.e task is action ,action2,action3   t should execute  action >> action2 >> action3

Comment: @jayesh_mahajan I have trouble understanding what you mean with `taks of airflow dag`, what are the variations of your input and what do you expect as output, what is `action[23]` (edit your question), if you want the top block of code you can put it all in a snippet